# When should I start to use a third party batch email system

Tags: email, mailing-list

Inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272109/sending-email-broadcasts) regarding email broadcasts

I was wondering at what point I should begin to use a third party to handle batch emails (opt-in).

I'm currently expecting several emails a week ranging between 10-500 email addresses.

Is it worth-while to use a third party for this scale?

I don't expect these emails to contain any significant amount of images (company logo is all)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/58750/safe-mailing-list-operation/

Answer (score 1):

How much is your time worth, vs how much will it cost to have an external service do it for you?

How many people are in your IT staff should you need to support your own mailing lists?

Is [mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html) or similar Good Enough™?

I know of one company near where I live in NC (iContact) that is pretty cheap to use. I'm sure there are myriad others, too :)